# Is the complement of a dense and open set also dense?

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that:
The complement of a dense and open set is nowhere dense.

My Attempt:
Let $A \subseteq X$ be dense, this means $\overline{A}=X$

$\overline{X-A}=X-Int(A)=X-A$

The last equation holds because A is open.

If now $X-A=X \Rightarrow A=\emptyset$
But A being empty is a contradiction to A being dense.

Is this correct?

Comment: The title and posted question don't match.

Comment: Does your conclusion match the statement that you're trying to prove? It looks like you made correct deductions but arrived at a place that's rather different from what you're trying to prove.

Comment: @GregMartin A being the empty set is a contradiction to A being dense. So the answer would be no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\operatorname{Int}(X-A) = X - \overline{A}$ and as $A$ is dense....

Comment: This just proofs that the Intern of $X-A=\empty$

Comment: @John.W which is what’s needed to show $X-A$ nowhere dense.

Comment: I don't understand why. Could you explain

Comment: @John.W $-A$ is closed and has empty interior. So by definition it’s nowhere dense.

Comment: Right, thank you!